# load images from array in json

Tags: jquery, json, load

Not sure why this is not loading. Any help would be great.

//images.json

```
{  
 "images": [
  {"title": "Image One", "url": "image1.jpg"},
  {"title": "Image Two", "url": "image2.jpg"},
  {"title": "Image Three", "url": "image3.jpg"}
 ]
}
```

//application.js

```
function loadImages(url, container) {
    //get the JSON object
    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
        if (typeof data === 'object') {
            $.each(data['images'], function (key, image) {
                var mylist = '<li><img src="' + image['url'] + '" alt="' + image['title'] + '"></li>';
                $(body).append(mylist);
            });
        }
    });
};


 $(function(){
     loadImages('images.json', '#mylist');
  });
```

//html

```
 <ul id="mylist"></ul>
```

Comment: are you getting an error? If so, what is the error?

Comment: can you set up a jsbin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
$(container).append(mylist);
```

Comment: Are you sure your getJSON's callback was invoked? try to log or alert to check

Comment: yeah nothing is being called??

Comment: try to get rid of this line if (typeof data === 'object') {

Comment: "HierarchyRequestError: Node cannot be inserted at the specified point in the hierarchy"

Answer (score 0):

You've missed the quotes here:

```
$(body).append(mylist);
```

It should be:

```
$('body').append(mylist);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing like `$(body)`, it should be `$('body')`. Also in your case it must be `$(container)`

Answer (score 0):

You need one level more loop:

```
$.each(data, function (key, image) {
    $.each(image, function(i,val){
        var mylist = '<li><img src="' + val.url + '" alt="' + val.title + '"></li>';
        $('body').append(mylist);
    })
});
```

Of course, if you wanna append to container, change $('body') to $(container)